# How to get the user with guild.members.get()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm having some troubling getting a user to add a role to.

```js
const DonatorAdd = (client, message, args, m_db, m_default, config, moment, server) => {
  var guild = message.guild.id;
  var member = guild.members.get(args[1]);
        if (!member.roles.has('590384740989796392')){ member.addRole('590384740989796392').catch(console.error); }
        if (!member.roles.has('605482684625453056')){ member.addRole('605482684625453056').catch(console.error); }
        if (!member.roles.has('605482688316440599')){ member.addRole('605482688316440599').catch(console.error); }
}
```

All I get is this error:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined" on "var member =
>   guild.members.get(args[1]);"

And args[1] is really an ID.

Comment: The error suggeats that `members` is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `guild` is `message.guild.id`. But this is only the id and not the guild it self. You should use `message.guild` instead of its id.